# DEV 501 - Programming Assignment Schedule

Tags: certification, dev501

The http://certification.salesforce.com/developers site states :

> The programming assignment is available periodically throughout the
>   year per the schedule listed below. Eligible candidates can register
>   for the programming assignment and essay exam in Webassessor during
>   open registration.

From this site it can be seen that all registration windows are currently closed (15-Dec-2013) Does anyone have a suggestion or approach to getting accepted into an "open" registration window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I signed up with in 10 minutes of when it was available.  I suggest trying to make yourself available at the hour it comes out.  There was something on a Linkedin thread a year or two ago that Salesforce would give preference to those who had not yet taken it. Sorry, can't find the link for it right now. If you don't get registered you could try contacting Salesforce directly as well.

The best strategy is to try to make yourself available near the hour when it comes out and register immediately.  It was opened for registration at 8 AM Pacific time when I registered.  I registered within 10 minutes of it being open.

Comment: Don't rely on doing it on the day, be online within the hour regardless of the timezone you're in!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wait for next window. It will be published soon by Salesforce Certification team.

There are very limited slots in every Quarter and it gets filled in few hours only. Next assignment will be approximately in coming March.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that folks who are eligible for the test get an email about registering approximately two months before the assignment and must register promptly or wait for the next opportunity.